# NoSQL approach: design table "scheme"

Tags: database-design

We need to store simple log data in a database, but we also need to get and filter data in realtime, based on 'user', simple 'tag' (ie. redis, memcache, php, mysql, etc.) and timestamp. We need to scale horizontally and real fast data access on billions rows.

In a SQL approach, table can be like this:

```
ID | timestamp | tag | user       | log text
1  | 19543532  | 1   | root       | { text log }
2  | 19543532  | 3   | redis-user | { text log }
```

where tag 1 and 3 are different and related to another table (ie. tag_id | tag_name). I think this is a relational approach and we can create three index (timestamp, tag and user) in order to speed up data access.

What is a good practice to reproduce this in a NoSQL database like DynamoDB (AWS) where we can create only HASH or RANGE index? Does a SQL database fit better than a DynamoDB?

My first attempt is:

**First table**: ID hash index

```
ID | log text
1  | { text log }
2  | { text log }
```

**Second table**: USER, TIMESTAMP range index

```
user | timestamp | id
root | 123145122 | 1
redis| 123491241 | 2
```

**Third table**: TAG index

```
tag        | id
debug      | 1
production | 2
```

Thank you in advice!

Answer (score -1):

w/o any secondary index I can think of PIVOT. (Data in Key-Value pair way)

[image]

Depending on the usage and query you are expecting you need to decided if key "LogText" needs to go in to another table or ok to put in Table-2.

You can have key on both columns and that will give you option of defining local secondary index to improve performance for complex queries like

ALL DATA where (TimeStamps is between x and y) and User = "ABC"

this can be done in two steps,

```
select ALL data where KeyIDs are IN 
( get unique KeyIDs for that satisfy this WHERE conditions.)
```

Comment: EAV (entity-attribute-value) models are famous for their poor performance; you can't honestly offer this as a solution that must "scale horizontally" and provide "real fast data access on billions rows".